# If $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =L $ , then what we can say about $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$?

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, limits-without-lhopital

$f$ and $g$ are differentiable functions so that they have the first derivative in a neighborhood of a point $x_0$, and so that $g(x)\neq0$ and $g'(x)\neq0$ in a neighborhood of a point $x_0$.

It also holds:
$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0}  g(x) = 0$ .

If $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} =L $ , then what we can say about  $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ ?

The same question I have if
$\lim_{x\to x_0} f(x) = \lim_{x\to x_0}  g(x) = \infty $ .

I am aware that if I would have the opposite, that $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)} =L $ , then I would have that  $\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)}{g(x} =L $ due to L'Hospitals rule, but I'm not sure what can I say about the opposite. I tried to find some examples when this is not true but I failed finding some...

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the limit $\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=L$, then, assuming that $\lim_{x\to x_0}f(x)=\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=0$, the limit$$\lim_{x\to x_0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)},\tag1$$*if it exists* it must be equal to $L$. This follows from L'Hopital's Rule. But the limit $(1)$ doesn't have to exist. For instance, take $x_0=0$, $f(x)=x^2\left(2+\sin\left(\frac1{x^2}\right)\right)$ and $g(x)=x$. Then $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}=0$, but the limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{f'(x)}{g'(x)}$ doesn't exist.

Comment: Doesn't your example fail to satisfy the requirement that $g$ and $g'$ are nonzero on some neighborhood of $x_0$?

Comment: @Joe Indeed. I've edited my answer. Thank you.

Comment: Maybe I'm confused, but I still see $g(x)=x$ with $x_0 = 0$, so $g(x_0)= 0$

Comment: @Joe The OP wrote that $\lim_{x\to x_0}g(x)=0$. Since $g$ is continuous, we must have $g(x_0)=0$. I assumed that the condition that $g(x)\ne0$ in a neighborhood of $x_0$ meant that, for some $\varepsilon>0$, $g(x)\ne0$ for each $x\in(x_0-\varepsilon,x_0+\varepsilon)\setminus\{x_0\}$.

Comment: Ah, I see, excellent point.